# xslt syntax: Use a variable into another

Tags: xslt, variables, syntax

I'm trying to do something like :

```
<xsl:variable name="typetest" 
              select="substring-before(
                         (substring-after(base-uri(),'Test_')),
                         '_'
                      )"/>          
<xsl:variable name="minAdd"+"$typetest" 
              select="teststep[@name='add"$typetest"Etalon']/@min"/>
```

I can't find the right way to use my var $typetest in both the name and the select of the other var.
I'dont know if it is possible, i am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: You can't do exactly that, but maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve there might be a different way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Showing us code that doesn't work isn't a good way of explaining your requirement. But you seem to be under the impression that XSLT variables work by textual substitution, which is not the case. A variable reference $x is an expression that evaluates to a value (not a fragment of program text), and you can only use it where a value is expected.

Comment: First of all, this is not even proper XML... Second, why you want a dynamic name for variables? Why you would want that for any language other than XSLT? If you want some kind of a key map structure, why don't you use an intermediate XML result?

Answer (score 1):

A variable name must be a valid [`qname`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-qname). It cannot be the result of an expression. [Source:](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variables-and-parameters)

```
<!-- Category: declaration -->
<!-- Category: instruction -->
<xsl:variable
  name = qname
  select? = expression
  as? = sequence-type>
  <!-- Content: sequence-constructor -->
</xsl:variable>
```